# hide result on same node in block (view)

Tags: views

I have 3 pages, vacation1, vacation2, vacation3. Under each page there is a block-view with fields (title, image, summary) that links to the other pages. I want to have on vacation1 links to vacation2 and vacation3, but my views show all the results. I wan't to filter out the result of the current node. How can I set the filter for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the contextual filter option here. You can get current page nid using contextual filter as shown in screen shot and can filter out the result.

[image]

[image]